# JDBC callableStatement.setDouble() getting 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have researched online for the last hour but can't figure the solution to this problem.

So, I have

```
for (BalanceBreakDownFee breakDownFee : tuitionFee.getBalanceBreakDownFees()) {
    System.out.println("Balance Breakdown Fee Description : "+breakDownFee.getDescription());
    System.out.println("Balance Breakdown Fee Amount : "+breakDownFee.getAmount());
    CS_addBalBreakDownFee.setString(1, breakDownFee.getDescription());
    CS_addBalBreakDownFee.setDouble(2, breakDownFee.getAmount());
    CS_addBalBreakDownFee.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
    CS_addBalBreakDownFee.executeUpdate(); 
    int balanceBreakDownFeeId = CS_addBalBreakDownFee.getInt(3);
}
```

Prior to executing the `for each` loop above, I have also tried to print the value of `breakDownFee.getAmount()` which returns a double value. Here's the output.

```
Description :Downpayment
Amount : 8000.0
Description :First Quarter
Amount : 2663.28
Description :Second Quarter
Amount : 2663.28
```

For some reason, when I make a call for `CS_addBalBreakDownFee.setDouble(2, breakDownFee.getAmount());` I get an error which points to the `setDouble()` line.

```
java.sql.SQLException: 'Infinity' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setDouble(PreparedStatement.java:3252)
```

As you can see, I tried printing the `breakDownFee.getAmount()` within the for-each loop to see what value it gets to compare to previous print above.

And I get this,

```
Balance Breakdown Fee Description : Downpayment
Balance Breakdown Fee Amount : 8000.0
Balance Breakdown Fee Description : First Quarter
Balance Breakdown Fee Amount : Infinity
```

I don't understand why it won't accept the **2663.28** double value. It appears that `jdbc` is reading it as `'Infinity'`

Also, to add more details, the **mysql** column which stores the amount is set to `DECIMAL(10,2)`

Any thoughts or suggestion on how I can store the **2663.28** value? Is this a problem with the 2 decimal places? If so, how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be using floating-point for money in the first place. You should using `DECIMAL` in SQL, and `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: I'm surprised if a double precision column would not accept infinity as value, as it is a valid double precision value. What is the actual type of that column?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The actual type of the JTable column containing the amount is set to an object type.

Comment: I was talking about the type of the column in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with JDBC at this point.  Your problem is with how you're getting your list of fees.

```
System.out.println("Balance Breakdown Fee Amount : "+breakDownFee.getAmount());
```

has nothing to do with JDBC, and yet, it is giving the java reserved value of Infinity.  You need to investigate what is happening to the amount between the time you checked it before the loop, and when you check it in the loop.

However, when you do solve that, you might still have a problem of what to do with the Java reserved values of Infinity and NaN (not a number).  In cases where this is possible, most people just check for that specifically and insert a null instead of the value.  The semantics of your application may differ.